# Convert multi list to dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from a list of lists. I have a list of name and marks like:

```
str=[
["Amit", 23],
["Amit", 127],
["Rahul", 3],
["Rahul", 71],
["Deepak", 31],
["Rahul", 22],
["Amit", 81]
]
```

to a dictionary with key as name and value as average marks like:

```
{"Amit":77, "Rahul":32, "Deepak":31}
```

I was trying to get each list and then convert it to dictionary value. But I am getting error.

```
def highest_avg(str):
mydict={}
for each in str:
    my_dict=dict.fromkeys(each[0],each[1])
    print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use an `OrderedDict` of lists, since it appears you'd like to maintain order.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

o = collections.OrderedDict()
for i in data:
     o.setdefault(i[0], []).append(i[1])
```

Now that you're done appending data to the dictionary, calculate the mean key-wise.

```
for k in o:
     o[k] = sum(o[k]) / len(o[k])
```

If order is not paramount here, a vanilla `{}` dictionary would work just as well.

---

```
print(o)
OrderedDict([('Amit', 77.0), ('Rahul', 32.0), ('Deepak', 31.0)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from statistics import mean
```

1 . Store the `list` of `numbers` by its `key` using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for key,val in s: 
         d[key].append(val)       
>>> d
=> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Amit': [23, 127, 81], 'Rahul': [3, 71, 22], 'Deepak': [31]})
```

2 . Calculate the `mean` using [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean)

```
>>> out = {key: mean(val) for key, val in d.items()}

>>> out
=> {'Amit': 77, 'Rahul': 32, 'Deepak': 31}
```

#driver values :

```
IN :s = [['Amit', 23], ['Amit', 127], ['Rahul', 3], ['Rahul', 71],
         ['Deepak', 31], ['Rahul', 22], ['Amit', 81]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using standard Python methods:

```
myList=[
["Amit", 23],
["Amit", 127],
["Rahul", 3],
["Rahul", 71],
["Deepak", 31],
["Rahul", 22],
["Amit", 81]
]

myDict = dict()
for key, value in myList:
    if key not in myDict:
        myDict[key] = list()
    myDict[key].append(value)

for key, values in myDict.items():
    myDict[key] = sum(values) / len(values)

print(myDict)
```

First I get all values belonging to a certain key and then I calculate the mean value. Also note that str is a built-in variable, so I replaced it with myList.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

k = lambda x: x[0]
{k: sum(l)//len(l) for k, l in ((k, [x[1] for x in g]) for k, g in groupby(sorted(str, key=k), key=k))}
# {'Amit': 77, 'Deepak': 31, 'Rahul': 32}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension :

```
{x[0]:x[1] for x in str}
```

Or devide the data into two lists keys and values :

```
keys = [x[0] for x in str]
values = [x[1] for x in str]
dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Output :

```
{'Deepak': 31, 'Amit': 81, 'Rahul': 22}
```

Comment: This is not the OP's requirement. Even the desired outputs do not match. Pls go through the question once again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    data =[
["Amit", 23],
["Amit", 127],
["Rahul", 3],
["Rahul", 71],
["Deepak", 31],
["Rahul", 22],
["Amit", 81]
]

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data) #convert your list into a Pandas DataFrame

data_df

       0    1
0    Amit   23
1    Amit  127
2   Rahul    3
3   Rahul   71
4  Deepak   31
5   Rahul   22
6    Amit   81

agg_data = data_df.groupby(data_df[0]).agg(np.mean) #Group data on names & aggregate using mean of scores(values)

agg_data
         1
0         
Amit    77
Deepak  31
Rahul   32

agg_data.to_dict()[1] #Convert your Pandas DataFrame into dict using 'dict' orientation
#the [1] is the key that represents your column. Dict is created like this: {column -> {index -> value}}

{'Amit': 77, 'Deepak': 31, 'Rahul': 32} #This is the output
```

Hope this helps